# advising all delete and save methods in spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement whereby I need to advise all delete and save methods and send the deleted/saved record somewhere else.

I am using JpaRepository which has

- 6 x delete
- 3 x save

Basically I need to advise all these methods.  The trouble is that each of these has different method signatures and return types, sometimes accepting a Long, Object or List.  I am considering using aspects to achieve this but it seems that it would be nasty as I currently have 4 objects I need to audit which comes to 4 x 9 = 36 different pointcuts.  There are more of these to come so this would soon come into the hundreds.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you considered using JPA EntityListeners? http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/EntityListenersPrePersist.htm They can be hooked at various points of the JPA Entity lifecycle, like Pre/Post-Persist/Update/Delete.

Comment: This looks like it might be the way to go, however, I need access to a spring bean to send a JMS Message.  I wonder if this is possible using @EntityListeners.

Comment: Maybe I can: [Autowiring Spring beans in Hibernate/JPA entity listeners](http://guylabs.ch/2014/02/22/autowiring-pring-beans-in-hibernate-jpa-entity-listeners/)

Comment: Just an offer: If you cannot solve your problem by means of JPA listeners or similar, please share some code (the whole variety of method names and signatures, for example), then maybe I can suggest an aspect-based solution. On-board framework means designed for this purpose are probably preferable, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working as @sheltem suggested.  I used EntityListeners.  In my case I needed access to a spring bean and was able to it this way:

```
@Component
public class PublishEntityListener {

    private static PublishingService publishingService;

    @Autowired(
            required = true)
    public void setPublishingService(PublishingService publishingService) {
        this.publishingService = publishingService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //Allow the static dependency to be setup post construct as @EntityListeners are no spring managed
    }

    @PostPersist
    public void prePersist(DomainObject<?> entity) {
        publishingService.publish(getTopicName(entity), HttpMethod.POST, entity);
    }

    @PostUpdate
    public void preUpdate(DomainObject<?> entity) {
        publishingService.publish(getTopicName(entity), HttpMethod.PUT, entity);
    }

    @PostRemove
    public void onDelete(DomainObject<?> entity) {
        publishingService.publish(getTopicName(entity), HttpMethod.DELETE, entity);
    }

}
```

Comment: I was wondering why no body upvote this answer. I think they are lost in aop like me. Lets wait till all come.